# Pick Date from Jquery Calender and Check it WIth DB and Print Events on That Date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have a jquery calender that stores the selected date in variable "X"... i want to get the events stored on that date from Database and print them ... please help me out...

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Date:

```
<script>  var x='';
$('#calendar').datepicker({

altField: '#datepicker_send',

    inline: true,

    firstDay: 1,

    showOtherMonths: true,

    altFormat: "yyyy/mm/dd",

    dateFormat: "yyyy/mm/dd",

    dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],

     onSelect: function(dateText){
     $('#event-date').text(dateText)
      x=dateText;          
     // alert(x);
     $.ajax({ type: "POST", 
     url: 'check_events.php', 
      data: {dateText: x }, 
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data)
     { alert("data"); }
          } );
    }
    });
</script>
```

**check_events.php:-**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("users") or die(mysql_error());

if(isset($_POST['dateText']))

{

$x = date_format($_POST['dateText'],'YYYY-MM-DD');

//$uname = mysql_real_escape_string($x);

$sql_check = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM events WHERE date='$x'");

while($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_check))

{

//print_r($res);
echo json_encode($res);

}

}

?>
```

how to print $res json variable in ajax call...

Comment: It should be *<space>FROM instead of *FROM.

Comment: changed it but no use.... is printing data in alert("data") is correct??

Answer (score 0):

It should be `alert(data)` without the quotes. You are actually printing the string "data" instead of the `data` returned from the ajax call. 
Also it is a good practice to implement the ajax `error:` event to help you troubleshoot issues. Example below:

`$.ajax({
// your other stuff here
    error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4){
        var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3 + " " + p4;
        if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});`

Comment: ok will use ajax error from now.. and how to print $res variable in alert then??

Comment: Just call `alert(data);`. The `data` variable should contain the `$res` object sent from your server.